# Quiero cambiar el segundo input por un droplist

Tags: php

`



medicine)) {
$prescription_medicine = explode('###', $prescription->medicine);
foreach ($prescription_medicine as $key => $value) {
$prescription_medicine_extended = explode('***', $value);
$medicine = $this->medicine_model->getMedicineById($prescription_medicine_extended[0]);
?>

<option value="id . '*' . $medicine->name; ?>"
 selected="selected">
name;?>

```
                                                            <option value="1">Tomar 1 al Día x 3 Días</option>
                                                            <option value="2">Tomar 1 al Día x 7 Días</option>
                                                            <option value="3">Tomar 1 c/4 Hrs x 7 Días</option>
                                                            <option value="4">Tomar 1 c/6 Hrs x 7 Días</option>
                                                            <option value="5">Tomar 1 c/8 Hrs x 7 Días</option>
                                                        </option>
                                                    </select>


                                                <?php
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </select>`
```

Comment: pero los droplist son html que tiene eso que ver con php???

Comment: que te impide cambiarlo???

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.